TypeError: invalid BytesLike value (argument="value", value={ "data": "0" }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.0)
Smart contract :
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract UsernameRegistry {
    // Mapping from address to username
    mapping(address => string) public addressToUsername;
    // Mapping from username to address
    mapping(string => address) public usernameToAddress;

    event UsernameMinted(address indexed user, string username);
    event UsernameNotAvailable(address indexed user, string username);

    function mintUsername(string memory _username) public {
        require(bytes(_username).length > 0, "Username cannot be empty");
        
        // Check if the username is already taken
        if (usernameToAddress[_username] != address(0)) {
            emit UsernameNotAvailable(msg.sender, _username);
            return;
        }

        // Assign the username to the caller's address
        addressToUsername[msg.sender] = _username;
        usernameToAddress[_username] = msg.sender;

        emit UsernameMinted(msg.sender, _username);
    }

    function isUsernameAvailable(string memory _username) public view returns (bool) {
        return usernameToAddress[_username] == address(0);
    }

    function getUsername(address _address) public view returns (string memory) {
        return addressToUsername[_address];
    }
}

JS component :
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { useAccount, usePublicClient } from 'wagmi';
import { getContract } from '@/lib/contract'; // Assuming `getContract` is in a separate file

const UsernameRegistry = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [isAvailable, setIsAvailable] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const { address, isConnected } = useAccount();
  const publicClient = usePublicClient();

  const checkAvailability = async () => {
    if (!username) return;

    try {
      const contract = getContract(publicClient);
      console.log('Assigned contract instance:', contract); // Debugging

      const available = await contract.isUsernameAvailable(username);
      console.log('Raw response:', available);
      
      if (typeof available === 'boolean') {
        setIsAvailable(available);
      } else {
        throw new Error('Unexpected response type');
      }

      console.log('Username availability:', available);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error checking username availability:', error);
      setMessage('Error: Failed to check username availability. Please check the console.');
    }
  };

  const mintUsername = async () => {
    if (!address) return; // Ensure connected before minting

    try {
      const signer = await publicClient.getSigner();
      const contract = getContract(signer);
      console.log('Minting username:', username);
      const tx = await contract.mintUsername(username);
      await tx.wait();
      console.log('Transaction successful:', tx);
      setMessage('Username minted successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error minting username:', error);
      setMessage('Error: Failed to mint username.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (username) {
      checkAvailability();
    }
  }, [username]); // Only re-check on username change

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
      <main className="rounded-xl bg-white text-pink-500 mx-72 outline outline-offset-2 outline-pink-300 shadow-2xl">
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center my-6 mx-4">
          <div className="rounded-2xl bg-white">
            <div className="text-3xl my-4 px-28 cursor-pointer font-mono font-semibold">Mint your name</div>
            {isConnected ? (
              <>
                <div className="px-16">
                  <input
                    id="username"
                    name="username"
                    type="text"
                    className="outline outline-offset-2 outline-pink-300 rounded-lg my-4 font-mono text-md font-semibold text-pink-500"
                    value={username}
                    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Enter username"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="px-16 font-semibold font-mono">
                  <button onClick={checkAvailability}>Check Availability</button>
                </div>
                {isAvailable !== null && (
                  <p>{isAvailable ? 'Username is available!' : 'Username is not available.'}</p>
                )}
                <br />
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center my-4 mx-8">
                  <div className="rounded-2xl bg-gray-100 outline outline-offset-2 outline-pink-300">
                    <div className="text-2xl my-2 mx-4 cursor-pointer font-mono font-semibold text-black hover:text-pink-500">
                      <button onClick={mintUsername} disabled={!username || !isAvailable} className="py-2">
                        Mint
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {message && <p>{message}</p>}
              </>
            ) : (
              <p>Please connect your wallet to interact.</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UsernameRegistry;


Your question is unclear. Please format your code and errors properly. Explain what you're trying to achieve, the errors you're encountering, and the steps you've taken to resolve the issue. This will help our community assist you better.
